# LuaTeX cannot find existing TTF font

Tags: fontspec, luatex

Using `lualatex`, I get the following error:

```
</usr/local/share/fonts/HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi.ttf>
!LuaTeX error: cannot find OpenType font file for reading ()
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The file is present and readable:

```
$ otfinfo -i "/usr/local/share/fonts/HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi.ttf"
Family:              HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi
PostScript name:     HoodHeavenOrnamentsTwoSSi
Version:             001.000
Unique ID:           FontMonger:HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi
Copyright:           Copyright c 1995 CdExpert Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
```

and the name is correct in the cache:

```
  {
   ["familyname"]="HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi",
   ["filename"]={ "/usr/local/share/fonts/HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi.ttf", false },
   ["fontname"]="HoodHeavenOrnamentsTwoSSi",
   ["fullname"]="HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi",
   ["names"]={
    ["family"]="HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi",
    ["fullname"]="HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi",
    ["psname"]="HoodHeavenOrnamentsTwoSSi",
    ["subfamily"]="Regular",
   },
   ["size"]={},
   ["slant"]=0,
   ["weight"]=400,
   ["width"]=5,
  },
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: `</usr/local/share/fonts/HoodHeaven Ornaments Two SSi.ttf>` seems to indicate that *this* font was found. It must be another one which gives problems. Also: if you didn't get an "tfm not found" error, the missing font can't be a system font, it must be one used through `pdftex.map`.

Comment: What versions of `luatex`/`luaotfload` do you have? This a backend error, so the font have been found earlier (that is why you don't get a "tfm not found" error) but the backend chocked on it while generating the PDF (my wild guess is that `luaotfload` is telling the engine it is a CFF font while it is a TTF one).

Comment: @Khaled this is an up-to-date TL2011 install.

Comment: does removing the spaces from file name make any difference? Could you add `\directlua{texio.write_nl(font.fonts[font.current()].format, font.fonts[font.current()].psname)}` somewhere in your document where this font is selected, and check the log (you should get a line with `HoodHeavenOrnamentsTwoSSi` and `opentype` or `truetype` above it).

Answer (score 2):

I saved the ttf-file *without spaces* and tried it with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX and had no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HoodHeaven Ornaments One SSi}
\begin{document}

abcdefABCDEF

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using it with spaces in the name on another machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with another font (EB Garamond Italic) which was in a bad version in my system. After re-copying this font, everything works fine.

Comment: 'Too localized' on this basis

Comment: Yes indeed. I just had no idea when I asked...

Comment: Scary though that a problem with another font file can result in that error message...

Comment: I seem to be having this exact same problem; I have the same error message and it's while trying to use EB Garamond. How did you fix it?

Comment: I removed the font and replaced it again…